# Alterar numeração de figuras em Latex

Tags: latex

Existe algum modo de alterar a numeração das figuras em Latex?

Por exemplo ele inicia a figura como:

Figura 01: Legenda

Eu gostaria que ficasse neste formato iniciando em 2.1

Figura 2.1: Legenda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumo que `2.1` seja figura 1 da secção 2...

Nesse caso no preambulo, juntamos:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
```

Para que a numeração das figuras passe a incluir o número de secção (adaptar conforme o pretendido)

Exemplo minimalista:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document}
\section{Primeira sec.}

\section{Segunda sec.}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
    \fbox{Substituir pela Imagem A}
    \caption{figura A}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```